# Как динамично создавать кнопки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Хочу сделать бота для TG, и появился небольшой вопрос. Допустим, что у меня есть функция, которая позволяет смотреть список продуктов. И все бы ничего, но бот должен дать возможность выбрать продукт. Самая главная проблема в том, что список не фиксированный, и его могут пополнять вне кода. Если допустим я заведу фиксированный список, то я смогу сам сделать кнопки под этот список. Но если в список что-то добавят вне кода - кнопки для добавленного не будет.

Вопрос: как адаптировать кнопки под добавляющиеся элементы, чтобы кнопка была даже для товара, который появился вне кода?

Comment: Циклом пройтись по списку?

Comment: и...? Мне надо понять как создавать кнопки на лету, под новые товары

Comment: идешь по списку, на каждый элемент создаешь в цикле кнопку.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так. Псевдокод:

```
def create_button(text):
    button.create(label=text)

for element in list:
    create_button(element)
```